# How to get the most depth tuples with recursive function?

Tags: python-3.x

Using python, if I'm given this input,

```
(('Spinach', (())), ('Basil'), (('Chicken', )))
```

without iterations, how do I make the result output like this with recursive function?

```
Spinach Basil Chicken
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```py
data = (('Spinach', (())), ('Basil'), (('Chicken', )))

def print_r(data, sep='\n'):
    """
        Arg-1  : `data` -> Type: List/Tuple
        Arg-2  : `sep`  -> Type: String
        Return :           Type: None
    """
    
    if not data: return
    
    data = list(data)
    item = data.pop(0)

    if isinstance(item, str):
        print(item, end=sep)
    else:
        print_r(item, sep)
        
    print_r(data, sep)
    
print_r(data, sep=' ')
```